# Medical term for "holding urine for a long time"

Tags: terminology, human-physiology, organs

Sometimes I get/feel pain in my stomach because of holding urine for long time. Is there any medical terminology describing: "holding urine for a long time", or pain associated with this activity?

Comment: Holding in feces for a long time is called "stool withholding". I don't know if there's an equivalent term for urine. In future, consider posting such questions to http://health.stackexchange.com instead. Why do you hold your urine in? Are you a schoolteacher or a bus driver? It's not the wisest move to hold your urine in for a long time; it carries risks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A swollen organ may be described as **distended** if the swelling is symptomatic of a medical disfunction.
The purpose of most bladders is to collect and retain a fluid; if that fluid needs to be discharged periodically, and is not able to do so, then there is usually pain as a result of the distension.

Inability to urinate is known as **[ischuria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urinary_retention)** or **urinary retention**, and could be the result of obstruction to the urethra, could be a failure of the bladder to fully contract during urination, or could many other possible causes.